# Font acting differently on IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, styles

I have created a simple [page](http://jsfiddle.net/DGtPy/5/) with a div having text in it, the problem is when running in IE it is consuming 2nd line while when running in Firefox or Chrome it fits in single line.

Is there anyway to rectify this, or do you see anything in style that I have done wrong? If no then kindly explain why this is happening.

Following is the html and style

```
<div class="Footer">
Hi my name is Mutahar, This message was sent from Superman Computer Systems located at 1705 From, Markham, ON.
```

```
            * {
            color: #101010;
            font-family: tahoma;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }
        .Footer {
            color: #404040;
            font-family: tahoma;
            font-size: 10pt;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: left;
            width: 700px;
        }
```

Comment: Hits two lines for me (Chrome).

Comment: Which do you want, all of it on a single line? What if the screen size changes and it cannot fit on one line?

Comment: shouldn't you put text in a `<p>` tag?

Comment: @RenoYeo Not necessarily...

Comment: @VoidKing hmm. I mean, wouldn't it be simpler than declaring everything a `<p>` tag has?

Comment: @RenoYeo, No as I am getting this html from a webservice call and I have to show as it is, html alteration not allowed

Comment: @Paddyd, I want both of them to be consistent either both fit in single line or both should consume second line

Comment: You can't count on fixed font sizes and zoom settings. Your design should be adaptive, and account for flexibility. Don't try to force things.

Comment: @j08691 You can omit few words from the text to reproduce the issue

Comment: @RenoYeo Assuming you want everything a `<p>` tag has. But if you do, then yeah, use `<p>` tag, of course. I almost too often just use `<div>` or `<span>` depending on whether I want a block-level element or not :) I probably overuse those two tags :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to explicitly set a lot of things you may want to consider.

Firstly, as VegDork stated, you can use:

```
line-height: 14px;
```

However, as Paddyd stated, What if the screen size changes and it cannot fit on one line? Perhaps the default way that your browser handles this is not what you want.

You can try:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

If you want three dots to show where the text cuts off (will hide a single line of text where the contents would overflow the parent element and show three dots (...) at the end).

Or, for use with block elements:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To just hide the contents.

You can do other things, too, like force no word wrapping, which when combined with `overflow` or `text-overflow`, can force certain ways you may want to handle what happens when text would overflow for the element.

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

I get that you probably want that this line would all fit, in all browsers, all the time, but really, it's just not that simple. What if I, as a user, shrink the window down to the size of a common sticky note? Granted, I wouldn't expect it to be very legible, however, how your web page behaves under these size constraints can be (albeit, a bit painstakingly) fully customize-able, and many of the effects are dependent upon *how* you set the width and height of your elements (with px or percentages, for intance). My advice would be to grab other professional websites and start resizing the window and see how they handled it.

However, that having been said, just know that it is very refreshing when you finally let go of trying to make everything look exactly the same for every user, for this is un-achievable. Instead try to use CSS to control how your elements (or the text nodes therein) behave under certain circumstances (e.g., If I set the width of a main wrapper (`<div>`) for my site as 900px, it will, even if the window is resized, stay the same width and the parts of the element that would overflow are just hidden, however, if I use something, like say, 80%, you can watch the element resize as you shrink down the width of the window).

Comment: Thanks so much for detailed explanation, but I guess I was not clear enough while asking question thats why you misunderstood a little. Yea I want to fit the text in one line in all browsers but not all time, what I want is to fit that text in same amount of lines in all browsers at any given instance

Comment: @MuhammadMutaharAlam OIC, well, can't you just use `text-align: justify;`?

Comment: Tried that no luck :(

Comment: @MuhammadMutaharAlam Hmmm. You are remembering to clear your browser-cache with each attempt, aren't you? I mean, you probably are, but I am just having trouble trying to figure out *exactly* what you want, I guess.

Comment: @MuhammadMutaharAlam You have to understand that each browser will do things a little different. What's wrong with the text fitting all in one line in Chrome but consuming two lines in FireFox? Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes dude I understand that each browser is different, I just want to have a concrete reason behind this behavior

Comment: @MuhammadMutaharAlam Behind what behavior? I don't suppose you could post a couple of screen shots in the different browsers showing the difference? My guess is this: For certain rules and properties that have never been explicitly set in your CSS (font-size, line-height, whatever...) each browser may render its default for any given rule a little different than others. I would suspect that something of this nature is what is making it appear different, however, I don't know of anyone who has memorized all of the different ways each browser defaults to for all different styles.

Comment: @MuhammadMutaharAlam My point is this: I don't think you will always get a "concrete reason" behind why certain browsers do things one way, while another differs, nor will you always get an explanation of just what all the behavioral differences are. It would be better to try and just hash out what the best practices are (something I continue to try and learn more of all the time). A lot of the explanations come later when you have an "AHA!" moment or two (at least that's how it's been for me).

Comment: I find it that IE always renders text a bit bigger, on a mac, font appears bolder than windows. I am sure there is a reason behind it but sometimes you just don't have time to figure it out or it might take too long to research it and not worth company time. You can try resetting letter spacing and any text related css rules but it's hardly worth the effort when you need to support a huge variety of browsers

Comment: @Huangism Exactly. I suppose if you have all the time in the world to study such things (i.e., you're *not* on company time, and you have plenty of time of your own), then I suppose it can be very educational and, perhaps, very beneficial, but it would be quite a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting line-height for the div.

```
line-height: 14px;
```

Comment: did that but no change, here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DGtPy/6/)

Comment: I don't understand how the height of a line can determine the length of a line. Wouldn't this just make the line taller?